# What does the error: "Expression recursively calls the containing property 'length'" mean?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

Sometimes when I add a property to class like this:

```
Public Class Ship
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)

        End Set
    End Property
```

I get an error. When I delete and retype it, sometimes the error doesn't appear. What causes an error like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting a potential stack overflow.

You need a private member to back your property or an automatic property.

```
Public Class Ship
    Dim _name As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Or as a simple auto property: `Public Property Name As String`.